# Where is the issue with my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Ok, so I'm trying to use a javascript HTTPRequest to load an XML document called "chem_vocab.xml". However, whenever I tried to execute the function, nothing would happen. I placed a couple alert() lines so I could see where my breakdown was occurring. It appears that there's some issue between:

```
alert("Beginning Loading");
```

and

```
alert("XML Loaded");
```

The page will correctly alert "Beginning Loading...", but won't alert "XML loaded". Where is my issue?

```
function load_vocab(){
alert("Beginning Loading...");
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","chem_vocab.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

alert("XML loaded");

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("wordlist")[0];
x= x.getElementsByTagName("word")[0];
word = x.getElementsByTagName("spelling")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
definition = x.getElementsByTagName("definition")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

alert("XML parsing successful");

document.getElementById('spelling').innerHTML = word;
document.getElementById('definition').innerHTML = definition;
```

}

Comment: I am going to guess "it doesn't work". -1 for the non-descriptive title and lack of error reporting. (I suspect an exception is thrown.)

Comment: `alert` is sooo much better than `console.log`, right? `:P`

Comment: What line does the javascript console report that the error is happening on?

Comment: rather than `alert('XML Loaded')` Why don't you `console.log(xmlDoc)` and work out whether it IS ACTUALLY loaded?

Comment: Try using Firebug in Firefox? Web Developer Tools in Safari or Chrome? Why are you using alerts.

Comment: @DavidBarker - You are assuming that the line assigning to `xmlDoc` even executes.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your issue, but you're using an async Ajax call but not using a listener to know when it completes.  Even if your code didn't halt mysteriously, `xmlhttp.responseXML` would always be undefined.

Comment: Im not assuming anything... just pointing the OP to debug efficiently rather than 'assuming' it is loaded because his alert says so.

Comment: You are sending an asynchronous request but reading it as it was synchronous

Comment: If you have Chrome, the latest version of IE or firebug for firefox, you can troubleshoot ajax stuff easier.  F12 brings up some dev tools.  Click the "Network" tab and run your function.  You will see an entry if the request has been made.  From there, you can click on that to look at the request headers and response to help out a little more.

Comment: I just like alert. Firebug says the error is in line 10, where xmlDoc is null for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","chem_vocab.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Your Ajax request is asynchronous. Therefore, you *cannot* read the `.responseXML` property immediately after sending it. **(The value of `xmlDoc` will be null/undefined.)** You have to do it from within the `readystatechange` callback instead.

Since you appear to be inexperienced with doing Ajax, consider a third-party Ajax library (e.g. jQuery, or [miniajax](http://code.google.com/p/miniajax/) if you don't use a general-purpose library).

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                   xmlhttp.open("GET","chem_vocab.xml",false);                            and it worked fine. thanks.

Comment: @user1489314 You don't seem to understand what an asynchronous Ajax request is. You have to use a callback function do read the Ajax response.

Comment: It is allowable in the spec to make it non-ajax by specifying as such, yes its not reccomended but its a small use-case so I think its fine. [Check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11993217/874257)

Comment: @JosiahHester You mean "synchronous", not "non-ajax". Synchronous requests are Ajax, too.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, but I made that apparent in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

      alert("XML loaded");

      var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("wordlist")[0];
      x= x.getElementsByTagName("word")[0];
      word = x.getElementsByTagName("spelling")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      definition = x.getElementsByTagName("definition")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      alert("XML parsing successful");
      document.getElementById('spelling').innerHTML = word;
      document.getElementById('definition').innerHTML = definition;
    }
  }
```

Your code is asynchronous. You will have to wait for the response before you can do `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;`. So you need to add an event handler for the `onreadystatechange` event, so that you have the response. Thats what the above code does

Comment: This is a correct answer but I doubt it will mean anything to the author.

Comment: @arxanas : point taken. I'll add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your calling Asynchronously and expecting it to return Synchronously. Using this code makes the call non-blocking so your never loading a response.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","chem_vocab.xml",true); // True means non-blocking, you need a listener
```

Therefore this will always be null.

```
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Quick and dirty fix [according to this document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'chem_vocab.xml', false);
xmlhttp.send(); // because of "false" above, will block until the request is done 
                // and status is available. Not recommended, however it works for simple cases.

if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
```